# How to encourage users to update existing answers?

Tags: discussion, edits

One thing I really like to do on Stack Overflow is update documentation and existing answers for users that may come across my answer my using Stack Overflow or Google for common development questions. See a few examples here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/25232725/950427
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/38224549/950427

Instead of adding another answer or commenting to ask for a user to update their current answer, what is the best way to get users to comeback to update existing answers?

One thing I see is when users do not update existing answers, users will either downvote old answers or add new ones. Is this the type of behavior we would like in this community?

Comment: `Instead of adding another answer or commenting to ask for a user to update their current answer` What's wrong with either of those options?

Comment: `users will either downvote old answers or add new ones. Is this the type of behavior we would like in this community?` Again, what's wrong with either of these?  Why *wouldn't* we want people doing this?

Comment: Answers which are correct for older versions of languages/frameworks/libraries are still correct for those versions. Instead of updating an existing answer (which answers the original question), would it not be better to add a separate answer, which can be voted on separately (since it has a different "usefulness")?

Comment: Relevant https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261817/how-do-we-encourage-edits-to-obsolete-out-of-date-answers; tl;dr: SO seems to have forgotten the collaborative editing aspect of the site and that everyone benefits from having updated information at the top.

Comment: @Braiam Thanks for that. I might delete this because a better/similar question was already asked, thanks!